# Compounding errors in order to get a well defined "reasonable" range for the end result.

Tags: statistics, estimation, error-propagation, chemistry

I'm doing some data migration for a company, and there are some materials that are essentially "some things in aqueous solution." In a specification for this material this is defined as "Solids content, 36-40% ; Active content 30-32%" The Active content is a subset of the solids content.

Now, I need to enter this into a system hierarchically, i.e. the material 1 has x% solids content, and the solids themselves have y% active content.

If I were to take the "widest possible case" scenario (i.e. the lowest active content might still produce the highest solids content and vice versa), you would have 75%-88.89% Active content within the solid.  If I took the narrowest case (i.e. the active content will only ever be maximised when the solids content is at its highest), you would have 80%-83.33%.

I believe that both of these approaches are too extreme. My non-scientific approach would be to eyeball it, and say, realistically, you would put something like 78%-86%, but I believe there is a more rigorous process that will allow me to produce a "reasonable" end range.  I believe the correct approach would be to use the same way errors are usually propagated in experimental science, but it's been a long time since I did physics lab, and I'm unsure how I would apply this (and whether it would be valid).

Answer (score 1):

Standard error propagation in science assumes that the errors to be combined are uncorrelated, so that the deviation of one does not depend on the deviation of the others.  In the case of uncorrelated errors, where you are trying to find the sum of two quantities with errors $Z=X+Y$, the errors add as squares, i.e., the variances add:
$$\sigma^2_Z=\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y$$
If there is a correlation, this can be incorporated as well:
$$\sigma^2_Z=\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y+2Cov(X,Y)$$
and if there is perfect correlation, the errors do indeed add.

Comment: Hello Paul, thanks very much for you answer.  Could you work through the example I gave, using this method, assuming in the first case no correlation, and in the second case a perfect correlation?  If you prefer I will ask questions in the abstract, but I think that actually might end up taking more of your time than simply working through the example.  Many thanks

Comment: I also wonder whether this approach is in fact valid in my situation. The percentage 36%-40% represents an absolute minimum and maximum.  In this case is it statistically valid to represent this as 38% ±2% where 2% is sigma as outlined above?

Comment: @Some_Guy that's a good question!  The reality is that the when things are labeled with a range, the limits are not as "hard" as you might think.  For many things such labeled, the range represents a 95% confidence limit, or some other percentage.  For a problem assuming that the hard limits are there, the above formula will be still close to being correct, but not exact.  You would have to look at a joint distribution function, and the distribution within the range, to interpret it exactly.

Comment: For the uncorrelated example, we have an error for the first of 2%, and error  for the second at 1%.  The error of the sum will be $e_Z=\sqrt{0.2^2+0.1^2} \approx 0.22$.

Comment: For the perfectly correlated example.  $Cov(X,Y)=\sigma_X\sigma_Y$, so the errors will just add, and you get $e_Z=0.3$.

Comment: So I tried this with some test numbers and the results didn't make that much sense at all.  I did a bit of reading and I think the problem is that we should use proportional error, not absolute error. I suppose this is an easy mistake to make because the numbers are percentages, however still need to be expressed as relative errors (relative to the absolute number) for the above method to make sense (them being percentages is arbitrary here: you could call them weights in grams of a 100g whole and the numbers wouldn't change).

Comment: Take an exaggerated example where you have 45%-55% solids content, resulting in an 4.5-5.5% final Active content (i.e. the solids are only 10% pure).  You can see how a final error of +-5.02% doesn't make sense, whereas +-1.4% is at least on the face of it reasonable.  That being said, I'm still not certain this is the most statistically valid way to approach my problem, and I have a few more questions regarding the basis of this approach.  I'm going to cross post on the stats SE using the knowledge that I've gained from this one to produce a more pointed question.

Comment: Take an exaggerated example where you have 45%-55% solids content, resulting in an 4.5-5.5% final Active content (i.e. the solids are only 10% pure). You can see how a final error of +-5.02% doesn't make sense, whereas +-1.4% is at least on the face of it reasonable. I'm going to  post to the stats SE using the knowledge that I've gained from this one to produce a more pointed question. I also have a few further questions that this one has now raised, and I think I might be able to summarise them all more succinctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Some_Guy, ah, that's a different question!  You put the question's operations solely with addition, so the answer was limited to that  If there is a multiplication operation also going on (such as with the 10% pure), that will be handled differently.

Comment: For your example here, you would have to use the 10% pure number to get to the input.  The uncertainty in the final active ingredient would be 0.5%, not 5%, since that is what is ultimately added.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying here, and I don't understand how the above example I gave differs from my original question, except numerically

Comment: perhaps my original question wasn't all that clear.  I've posted a more "general" question, based on the same principles, that should give a lot more clarity on the situation.  Thanks for your help anyway.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303130/is-standard-error-propagation-appropriate-in-this-situation-and-if-so-how-and